# Compiling a c program on a 64 bit machine with a 32 bit binary

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit, libssh

I am currently trying to use the libssh.dll library to implement a c program that shall connect to remote computers.I am using gcc to compile the program. When compiling this program, I received this error:

```
i386 architecture of input file 'libssh/bin/libssh.ddl' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

I tried compiling the program with the -m32 flag, but then i receive these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: added to my makefile, but I still received the second set of errors as shown above

Comment: Try this:

export CFLAGS='-m32'
export CXXFLAGS='-m32'
export LDFLAGS='-m32'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the 32-bit version of the C library.

The 32-bit libraries are required if you want to be able to compile and link with the `-m32` option.

Have you installed `cygwin32` ?

Comment: I am using cygwin, I do not have linux installed.

Comment: I shall try installing cygwin32 bit and compiling it with the gcc library present there

Comment: I have installed the cygwin 32 bit version for windows, and it is working correctly. Thank you for the help :)