# Java JNI and Cygwin

Tags: java, java-native-interface, cygwin

i try to write a simple Java JNI code like HelloWorld. I'm trying to follow an example but i think it's much too old and the commands are outdated. I have reinstalled Cygwin and i tried minGW.  Everthing is fine but i get this Error every time if i want to build the .dll:

```
   "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Tobias/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorldNative'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/HelloWorldNative.dll
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Tobias/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorldNative'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/HelloWorld.o.d"
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -m32   -c -g -I../../../../../Programme/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/include -I../../../../../Programme/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/include/win32  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/HelloWorld.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/HelloWorld.o HelloWorld.c
mkdir -p dist
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -m32    -o dist/HelloWorldNative.dll build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/HelloWorld.o  -shared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/HelloWorldNative.dll' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/HelloWorldNative.dll] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Tobias/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorldNative'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Tobias/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorldNative'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 4s)
```

best regards,

T. Jung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because you are trying to compile a 32-bit program but do not have the 32-bit libraries installed?  You may need to install the 32-bit version of cygwin.  See [Compiling a c program on a 64 bit machine with a 32 bit binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912004/compiling-a-c-program-on-a-64-bit-machine-with-a-32-bit-binary)